# Single GET by rowkey using Spark (2) Hortonworks Connector

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-2.0

Is it possible to do a GET request to retrieve a single record by rowkey using SHC? [Spark `2.1`, SHC `1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11`]

I see that [SHC](https://hortonworks.com/blog/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/)

> treats both Scan and Get in a similar way, and both actions are
>   performed in the executors

As the table has millions of records, I do not want to perform a full scan to retrieve the record I need, but just retrieve the single record by rowkey.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find the answer of this question yet? I wonder how too